# Serious Startup Error: Error code 583

Tags: warning-messages, kernel-startup

I can't start Mathematica 10.2 in Windows 8.1 64 bit, I'm getting this error even after I uninstalled and re-installed.

[image]

I emailed support a couple fo days ago, but I'm yet to hear from them and I need to get to work ASAP, any ideas?

Comment: Can't you revert your whole system to a point in time where everything worked via a backup?

Comment: No. I don't have a backup.

Comment: [This article](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12464?lang=en) may help you.

Comment: This same error was reported in question 94541, subsequently deleted.  It also was reported on a Russian Mathematica site, where it was put on hold.  It seems likely that Wolfram Inc is your only resource.

Comment: There is a [refresh your PC without affecting your files](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/restore-refresh-reset-pc#) function in windows. That might help. For the future you should seriously consider having some kind of backup, especially for your important, work-related files!

Comment: Thanks JHM, a clean start did the trick.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This error message has occurred before with a corrupted init.m file.

Check your init.m files if you have edited them. Otherwise, [the article @JHM linked to](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12464?lang=en) you should fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows, remove directory `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica`.